# Detecting over-parameterization in GLMM: number of observations to number of parameters ratio?

Tags: regression, random-effects-model, glmm

I'm using generalized linear mixed models (GLMM) to model the effect of several testing conditions on the binary outcome of a behavioral trial. There were 40 individual subjects in my experiment, and I have 16 responses from most individuals. I used a crossed, within-subjects design, so I have observations from every individual for every combination of experimental conditions (with the exception of a handful of subjects that contributed fewer than the full complement of responses). I am interested in fitting random intercepts to control for repeated measures from individuals that may have different average responses -- after that, I want to focus on fixed effects.

I have three continuous fixed effects and one factor, which has four levels. I am also interested in one two-way interaction between continuous variables, and one two-way interaction between a continuous variable and the factor. There are, including the global intercept, 11 parameters that I am interested in estimating. All of these effects are biologically relevant and it doesn't make sense to eliminate any of them.

An outside reviewer suggested to me that this model is over-parameterized with 40 individuals and 11 parameters. I've been trying to wade through the literature about how these models are used in biology and it sounds like some authors think GLMM models are usually over-parameterized, but it's not clear to me whether 40 and 11 are the relevant numbers to consider.

My questions are:

1) Some sources recommend "rules of thumb" about the number of observations (n) per the number of parameters (k) to be estimated. Estimates of how many observations per parameter (n/k ratio) are needed to avoid over-parameterization seem to vary wildly between 2 and 15. With this n/k ratio, does the number of observations refer to the number of individual data points (in this case 602, which the model output shows as the number of observations) in a repeated measures design or the number of individuals from which those measurements are made (in this case 40)? That is, is my n/k ratio 602/11, 40/11, or something else? I am largely interested in understanding the effect of a testing condition on the outcome of the trial. That is, I don't intend to make any inferences about differences between individuals.

2) What are the clearest symptoms of an over-parameterized model, assuming the model converges without difficulty? I gathered that estimating the variance in the random effect at 0 might indicate an over-parameterized model, as would estimating the correlations between parameters at plus or minus 1. If you can point me toward resources that clearly explain detecting over-parameterization in linear mixed models with random intercepts, that would be helpful.

GLMM model output from the function lme() in the nlme package in R (correlations have been rounded to two digits for ease of reading):

```
    > summary(mod)
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
    Data: dat
    AIC      BIC    logLik
    845.5477 902.5113 -409.7739

    Random effects:
    Formula: ~1 | ID
    (Intercept)  Residual
    StdDev:   0.1217243 0.4558754

    Fixed effects: Binary ~ A+B+C+as.factor(D)+A:C+C:as.factor(D) 

                        Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value  p-value
    (Intercept)      0.5948202 0.06013391 552  9.891594  0.0000
    A                0.1600193 0.07195900 552  2.223756  0.0266
    B                0.0002061 0.01402861 552  0.014689  0.9883
    C               -0.8825978 0.20002683 552 -4.412397  0.0000
    as.factor(D)1    0.0125315 0.08007395 552  0.156499  0.8757
    as.factor(D)2   -0.1599268 0.08033099 552 -1.990848  0.0470
    as.factor(D)3   -0.0774118 0.07994780 552 -0.968279  0.3333
    A:C             -0.2329563 0.16697935 552 -1.395120  0.1635
    C:as.factor(D)1  0.0191221 0.27577004 552  0.069341  0.9447
    C:as.factor(D)2  0.4144852 0.27240416 552  1.521582  0.1287
    C:as.factor(D)3  0.6366380 0.27432079 552  2.320779  0.0207

    Correlation: 
        (Intr)  A     B     C    D1    D2    D3    A:C  C:D1  C:D2
    A   -0.03                                                                                                        
    B    0.04 -0.61                                                                                                
    C   -0.70  0.08 -0.23                                                                                   
    D1  -0.67 -0.01 -0.02  0.52                                                                      
    D2  -0.67 -0.01  0.02  0.51  0.50                                                               
    D3  -0.67 -0.01  0.02  0.51  0.50  0.50                                                    
    A:C  0.01 -0.94  0.73 -0.08  0.01  0.01  0.01                                         
    C:D1 0.50  0.01  0.05 -0.69 -0.76 -0.37 -0.37 -0.00                              
    C:D2 0.50  0.02 -0.03 -0.67 -0.38 -0.76 -0.38 -0.03 0.49                       
    C:D3 0.49  0.01 -0.04 -0.65 -0.37 -0.37 -0.75 -0.01 0.48 0.49        

    Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
           Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
    -1.6979366 -0.8476542 -0.2960492  0.9789701  1.7910003 

    Number of Observations: 602
    Number of Groups: 40
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which sample size depends on how variable the individuals are. If each person's repeated measures are highly similar, then the repeated measures don't covey much information and your "effective" sample size gets closer to 40. I would consider your question to be a model selection problem. Informally, AIC/BIC comparisons are a good start for addressing the reviewer's concerns. Cross validation comparing this model to simpler models would also help your argument.